# (problema con for...if loop y arrays dentro de arrays) Calculadora de comisiones

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, bucles

estoy aplicando los conocimientos que he aprendido en js hasta ahora (strings, loops y arrays) para hacer una calculadora de comisiones de ventas (planes telefónicos), explico brevemente:

1. Tengo una variable `rawData` que almacena los datos en bruto de las ventas que hago. (es un array con varios strings largos que contienen los datos de la venta.

   `var rawData = [ '(out)1128509010 12gb 70*12 - 1665455876A', '(out)2932526439 4gb 80*12 - 1665458623A', '(out)2944285556 12gb 70*12 - 1665469491A' ];`
2. Aplico unos cuantos métodos para organizar la info utilizando las variables `betterData`, `data` e `inventory` junto con de un par de loops. De esta manera logro que `inventory` almacene los string iniciales en un array de arrays. La consola retorna así:

   `inventory = [["out","1128509010","12gb","70*12","1665455876A"], ["out","2932526439","4gb","80*12","1665458623A"], ["out","2944285556","12gb","70*12","1665469491A"]]`
3. Hasta ahi todo bien, luego necesito sacar el elemento de los arrays que se refiere al plan que vendí, en este caso tenemos dos ventas de planes de 12gb y una de 4gb. Ahí aplico un **for loop** que no estoy seguro si está bien estructurado:

   ```
   let planes = [];

   for (i = 0; i <= inventory.length; i++) {
     planes.push(inventory[i][2]);
   }
   ```

   Ahí el CodePen me da un mensaje de error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined", sin embargo la variable `planes` me devuelve `["12gb","4gb","12gb"]` en la consola. Es decir, que se logró el objetivo.
4. Por último aplico un **for...if loop** para calcular el monto de la comisión que voy a hacer con cada venta y sumarla a una variable `comision` para obtener un total.

   > ```
   > let comision = 0;
   > for (i = 0; i <= planes.length-1; i++) {
   >   if (planes[i] === '12gb') {
   >     comision += 3680 * 0.2;
   >   } else if ( planes[i] === '4gb') {
   >     comision += 1929 * 0.2;
   >   } else {
   >     console.log('error');
   >   }
   > }
   > console.log('Tus comisiones son: $' + comision);
   > ```

Este último bloque de código nunca llega a funcionar, la variable `comision` devuelve **"comision is not defined"**

Probé la misma estructura de código pero simplificada en otro Pen con letras y números y funciona perfectamente. Dejo acá los pens:

[**Pen de la calculadora principal**](https://codepen.io/luissimosa25/pen/oNZKYWL)

[**Pen del código simplificado que si funcionó**](https://codepen.io/luissimosa25/pen/poeMezR)

Comment: En el bucle del punto 3 tienes puesto i <= inventory.length, inventorytiene una logitud en este caso de 3 por toatno su último índice es 2. Así que esa condición del for debe ser i<inventory.length.  El resto he probado y me funciona, sale una comisión de $1857.8

Comment: No esparaba una respuesta tan rápida, muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: En este caso, como es un simple error, la cerramos como error tipografico.. pero muy buena primera pregunta!